# Java: GUI acts weird after importing into netbeans, feels like some kind of Java version changed

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

[image]

This is what it should look like. It looked like that before, but then I imported project into Netbeans and it messed up, buttons became weird and roundish.

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

Even though background is set to grey, it appears white, Opaque is true. 
It feels like some kind of java renderer version has changed (if such thing even exists)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: There is no code that's relevant to GUI really, it's all built using Netbeans GUI builder. And as I said - nothing was changed except imported into Netbeans

Comment: Seems like an issue with the [theme](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).